# How to automatic redirect (first-time only) a page based on browser language?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-headers

Currently I have the following code in my .htaccess file (Dutch example):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^nl [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !nl
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/nl/$1 [L]
```

However, when a visitor decides to change the language via language switcher,  they will still see the version of their browser language (eg if they want to visit the English version but have `%{HTTP:Accept-Language}` set to `nl`, they can never to go the English page because of redirect.

Moreover, some page has another file name in the language-specific directory (eg. `example.com/example/` in the canonical site, and `example.com/nl/voorbeeld/` for the Dutch version). In this case, a 404 error will occur, with the existing RewriteRules. How can I avoid this without specifying each page? I do have `<link rel="alternate">` in the head of each page.

Should I use php instead? How much will it slow down the response speed?

---

**Update**: as suggested, I now use a banner instead of auto-redirect to remind user for the exist of localised page. With the following solution just for someone that may come up with the same though:

The server will detect if user has specified his/her preferred language, in case that is empty and the `HTTPS_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` is different than the page user is requesting, a banner will occur on the top of the page unless `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` is also empty. I set `$browserlang` to the highest weighted `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` that matches the available language version the site has. and the banner is below:

```php
<form action="<?php if ($preflang == 'en') {
                        echo '/';
                    } elseif ($preflang == 'de') {
                        echo '/de/';
                    } elseif ($preflang == 'nl') {
                        echo '/nl/';
                    } elseif ($preflang == 'zh-Hans') {
                        echo '/zh-Hans/';
                    } elseif ($preflang == 'zh-Hant') {
                        echo '/zh-Hant/';
                    } else {
                        echo '/lang-switcher/';
                    } ?>" method="GET">
        <span><?php if ($preflang == 'en') {
                    echo 'Do you want to visit our site in English?';
                } elseif ($preflang == 'de') {
                    echo 'Möchten Sie die deutsche Seite besuchen?';
                } elseif ($preflang == 'nl') {
                    echo 'Wil je de Nederlandstalige site bezoeken?';
                } elseif ($preflang == 'zh-Hans') {
                    echo '若想访问中文网站，请点击跳转';
                } elseif ($preflang == 'zh-Hant') {
                    echo '若想訪問中文網頁，請點擊跳轉';
                } else {
                    echo 'Do you want to check if you can visit our site in your preferred language?';
                }
                ?></span>
        <button type="submit">
            <span xml:lang="<?php echo $preflang; ?>" lang="<?php echo $preflang; ?>"><?php if ($preflang == 'en') {
                echo 'Go';
            } elseif ($preflang == 'de') {
                echo 'Gehe';
            } elseif ($preflang == 'nl') {
                echo 'Ga';
            } elseif ($preflang == 'zh-Hans') {
                echo '跳转';
            } elseif ($preflang == 'zh-Hant') {
                echo '跳轉';
            } else {
                echo 'Go';
            } ?></span>
        </button>
    </form>
```

I do think this code has a lot of room to improve but I guess I should ask in another question.

Comment: "Currently I have the following code in my .htaccess file" - And that is _working_? It looks like it would result in a redirect loop, unless you have another `.htaccess` file in the `/nl` subdirectory? (Is `/nl` a physical directory?) "when a visitor decides to change the language via language switcher, they will still see **the page** in their browser language." - What page? What does your "language switcher" do?

Comment: Yes I have the universal version at root directory (`/`) and language-specific version at `/langcode/` subdirectory. It works for redirecting, except the css files and any other request that's not in the same directory would break (say css file that I have in `/css/` instead of having also a copy under `/langcode/css/`) 

I also have a page with links to the language-specific homepage (eg. `<a href="https://example.com">English</a>` `<a href="https://example.com/nl">Nederlands</a>` and if one specifically want to visit the English version, they can't)

Comment: You should put your "update/answer" as an "answer".

Comment: _Aside:_ `<a href="https://example.com/nl">Nederlands</a>` - That URL should have a trailing slash, otherwise, mod_dir will append the trailing slash with a redirect (2nd request).

Comment: Sorry @MrWhite I didn't quite get where you mean? I think I do have a trailing slash at the end.

Comment: In other words, `https://example.com/nl` should be `https://example.com/nl/`. You omitted the trailing slash in the anchor tag in your comment above.

Comment: @MrWhite Oh yes, I didn't realise I leave that behind

Answer (score 2):

You should **NEVER** automatically redirect users based on language.  All methods of automatically detecting a user's preferred language are flawed.

- The `Accept-Language` header is often inaccurate for users. Users don't know how to configure it. It usually matches the language of the browser that was downloaded.  However, that is sometimes not the *preferred* language of the user. Especially because downloads often default to English which the user may understand well enough to use the browser, but would prefer some other language.
- Search engine crawlers may send `Accept-Language`, but they don't want to be redirect and would actually accept every language.

When you automatically redirect a request you confuse users and **kill your SEO**.  Rather than automatically redirecting you should put a prominent notice in the page in the detected language of the user.  Something like:

> This page is in German but your browser is set to prefer English. An English version of this page is available if you would prefer it.
>
> [Switch to English]

For further reading see my answer to [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization)

Comment: My first thought was that the browser language should be default to the system language which is generally set by user, instead of as configured by the language the package uses. And if a user specifically want to visit the site in another language than the HTTP-lang, they will not be redirected. But the latter practice cannot be archived in .htaccess settings.